# The domain of a Function

Tags: functions

$$y=x(18−2x)(13−2x) $$
$y$ is a function of $x$ , what is the contextual domain of this function (i.e. considering the meanings of the quantities $x$ and $y$ relative to the open-top box)? 
I've put this answer: $(-\infty,\infty).$

Comment: (Hint) y=x(18−2x)(13−2x) (this equation models the familiar open-top box, where y is the volume of the open-top box cut from a 13" x 18" sheet of paper when the square cutout has side length x )

Comment: you can exoand it also and upon expanding you can see something like this. 4x2-62x+234. And you can clearly see y is defined for all values of x. i.e domain is all real numbers and range is (-inf,inf)

Comment: @RajSharma "Contextual domain" differs from "domain" in the usual sense. It is asking the reader to provide those real numbers that are both admissible in the function *and* are reasonable in the context of the question. For example, $x$ must be greater than 0 in order for the function to reasonably model the volume of a box.

Comment: thanks I didn:t read it carefully. I thought it is just asking for domains. By the way if he had asked only for domains and range what would be the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem were asking only for the domain and range for the given equation where $y$ is a function of $x$, then both the domain and range would be all real numbers, i.e., $(-\infty,\infty)$. However, if $y$ represents the volume of an open box created from a 13" x 18" piece of paper, then each factor represents a side length of the box. So, in this context, we need the volume $y$ to be positive and we need each side to have positive length. Therefore, we require $x >0$, $18-2x>0$, **and** $13-2x>0$. All three inequalities will be satisfied when $0<x<\frac{13}{2}$.